# Using pre-written themes for Android

Tags: android, android-theme

This is driving my nuts and it's probably really simple.

I know how to change a theme in my app.  I think I just need to change this line in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

You just change `AppTheme` to whatever themes you have in `values/styles.xml`.

However, my `styles.xml` file is boring:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">

</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

</style>
```

I.e. I don't think there is a theme?

Where do I download themes?  What do I need.. presumably a `styles.xml` and some assets (e.g. images).  I'm mainly a back-end programmer and I just want something that looks a little more interesting than the default theme.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't download pre-written themes for android that i know of. You can use some snippets from the internet and make a styles.xml for yourself. For example the code below is a custom theme:

```
<resources>
  <!-- Base application theme is the default theme. -->
  <style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme">
  </style>

  <!-- Variation on our application theme that has a translucent
 background. -->
  <style name="Theme.Translucent">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/translucent_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">#fff</item>
  </style>

  <!-- Variation on our application theme that has a transparent
background; this example completely removes the background,
allowing the activity to decide how to composite. -->
  <style name="Theme.Transparent">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/transparent_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">#fff</item>
  </style>
  <style name="TextAppearance.Theme.PlainText" parent="android:TextAppearance.Theme">
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

Put this thing in the styles.xml file in the values folder. Change the `colorForeground` etc to create your own theme. Add your own images in the drawable folder and reference them here and so on.